# How to create a white box for content over an image background in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Right now, I have my text directly over the background image; but I want to add a white box *over* the background image so I can have my text in the white box instead (to be more visually appealing). I tried adding this to my CSS sheet:

```
.white-box {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

and this in the HTML page:

```
<body>
<div class="white-box">
Content
</div>
</body>
```

This does not change my webpage and when I search this issue online, I just see different versions of what I already tried (shown above)
[Here is what I am trying to achieve](https://startbootstrap.com/snippets/full-image-background/)

I appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this code. You don't need to use `position: absolute` if the image is placed on parent element (in my example `div.image` is parent of `div.content`).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.image {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://miro.medium.com/max/1200/1*mk1-6aYaf_Bes1E3Imhc0A.jpeg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding: 30px;
}

.content {
  background: white;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</div>
```

If you would like to render image on document body you can add `image` class to `<body>` instead of creating container div.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem! Also, love the image you used! XD

Answer (score 0):

Try to inspect the website and css it use. This give you better idea and improve your skills more (:

My approach would be set background image on outer div and set the overflow to scroll and then create the div inside it that has white backgound..as shown in the website